# ASP Update IIS Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I understand why users are "kicked" when you replace the web.config file, and know to ignore session variables etc.  However, I was curious if their was a way to notify the user of a "new" or "update" that is available and for them to log-out and back in.

Once the users logs out, then logs back in they have the most updated version.  Is this possible?

Comment: The user can't continue running the old version. They can only run what's on the server. So no, not possible with ASP.NET. If you wanted something more seamless, you'd need to architect your site more like a Single Page Application so that the logic is on the client.

Comment: @mason -- that is what I figured, but wasn't sure.  Thought I would reach out and look for an alternative (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

As a "standard" typical ASP.Net page, this is not possible.  Their are however a few 3rd party apps out their that will allow something like this. For example, NuGet can handle this.  Take a look at the link and these instructions are pulled directly from the link:

> The basic concept is this: Package up the first version of a website
>   as a NuGet package. Install this package in the website itself. I
>   know, crazy talk, right? Add a custom NuGet client that runs inside
>   the website and checks for updates to the one package that’s
>   installed. When the next version of the website is ready, package it
>   up and deploy it to the package feed for the website. Now, the users
>   of the website can be notified that an update is available.

[Update Manager](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx/)